# CSV File Parser in Ruby - Attempt No. 2

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

The following is my second attempt at a basic CSV parser in Ruby. I've addressed suggestions that I've got for my previous version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/70506/20714).

I have omitted all test cases - the code listing would be too long otherwise. You can look at the full code-base at [GitHub](https://github.com/dusan-rychnovsky/csv-parser) if you want to.

As opposed to the last version, the current solution supports:

- multiple different value delimiters,
- values surrounded by quotes,
- delimiters as a part of quoted values,
- quotes as a part of quoted values.

Please note that my intentions are not to implement a full-featured CSV parser, but to improve my Ruby programming skills. I'll appreciate any suggestions.

---

**csv_parser.rb**

```
require_relative 'line_parser'

# An exception to report that the given delimiter is not supported.
#
class UnsupportedDelimiterException < Exception
  attr_reader :delimiter

  def initialize delimiter
    @delimiter = delimiter
  end

  def to_s
    "Unsupported delimiter [#{@delimiter}]."
  end
end

# CSV file parser.
#
# USAGE:
# CsvFile.new(';').parse('data.csv').each { |row| puts row.firstname }
#
class CsvFile

  SUPPORTED_DELIMITERS = [ ",", "|", ";", " ", "    "]
  DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ","

  # Initializes the parser.
  # 
  # * *Args*    :
  #   - +delimiter+ -> The character to be used as delimiter. Defaults to
  # DEFAULT_DELIMITER. Must be one of SUPPORTED_DELIMITERS, otherwise
  # an UnsupportedDelimiterException is raised.
  #
  def initialize delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER
    if not SUPPORTED_DELIMITERS.include? delimiter
      raise UnsupportedDelimiterException.new delimiter
    end
    @line_parser = LineParser.new(Lexer.new delimiter)
  end

  # Parses the given CSV file and returns the result as an array of rows.
  #
  def parse file
    rows = []
    headers = @line_parser.parse file.gets.chomp
    file.each do |line|
      values = {}
      headers.zip(@line_parser.parse line.chomp).each do |key, value|
        values[key] = value
      end
      rows << CsvRow.new(values)
    end
    rows
  end
end

# CSV row.
#
class CsvRow

  # Creates a new CSV row with the given values.
  # 
  # * *Args*    :
  #   - +values+ -> a hash containing the column -> value mapping
  #
  def initialize values
    @values = values
  end

  # Returns the value in the column given as method name, or null if
  # no such value exists.
  #
  def method_missing name, *args  
    @values[name.to_s]
  end
end
```

---

**line_parser.rb**

```
require_relative 'lexer'

class ParseError < RuntimeError
end

# CSV line parser.
#
class LineParser

  # Initializes the parser with the given lexer instance.
  #
  def initialize lexer
    @lexer = lexer
  end

  # Parses the given CSV line into a collection of values.
  # 
  def parse line
    values = []
    last_seen_identifier = false
    tokens = @lexer.tokenize line
    tokens.each do |token|
      case token
        when EOFToken
          if not last_seen_identifier
            values << ""
          end
          break
        when DelimiterToken
          if not last_seen_identifier
            values << ""
            next
          else
            last_seen_identifier = false
          end
        when IdentifierToken
          if last_seen_identifier
            raise ParseError, "Unexpected identifier - a delimiter was expected."
          end
          last_seen_identifier = true
          values << token.lexem
      end
    end
    values
  end
end
```

---

**lexer.rb**

```
require_relative 'assertions'

class LexicalError < RuntimeError
end

class Token
end

class EOFToken < Token
  def to_s
    "EOF"
  end
end

class DelimiterToken < Token
  attr_reader :lexem

  def initialize lexem
    @lexem = lexem
  end

  def to_s
    "DELIMITER(#{@lexem})"
  end
end

class IdentifierToken < Token
  attr_reader :lexem

  def initialize lexem
    @lexem = lexem
  end

  def to_s
    "IDENTIFIER(#{@lexem})"
  end
end

# CSV line lexical analyzer.
#
class Lexer

  # Initialzes the lexer.
  # 
  # * *Args*    :
  #   - +delimiter+ -> The character to be used as delimiter.
  #
  def initialize delimiter
    @delimiter = delimiter
  end

  # Breaks the given CSV line into a sequence of tokens.
  #
  def tokenize stream
    stream = stream.chars.to_a
    tokens = []
    while true
      tokens << next_token(stream)
      if tokens.last.is_a? EOFToken
        break
      end
    end
    tokens
  end

  private

  def next_token stream
    char = stream.shift
    case char    
      when eof
        EOFToken.new
      when delimiter
        DelimiterToken.new delimiter
      when quotes
        stream.unshift char
        get_quoted_identifier stream
      else
        stream.unshift char
        get_unquoted_identifier stream
    end
  end

  def get_unquoted_identifier stream
    lexem = ""
    while true do
      char = stream.shift
      case char
        when delimiter
          stream.unshift char
          return IdentifierToken.new lexem
        when eof
          return IdentifierToken.new lexem
        else
          lexem << char
      end
    end
  end

  def get_quoted_identifier stream
    char = stream.shift
    assert { char == quotes }
    lexem = ""
    while true do
      char = stream.shift
      case char
        when eof
          raise LexicalError, "Unexpected EOF within a quoted string."
        when quotes
          if stream.first == quotes
            lexem << quotes
            stream.shift
           else
             return IdentifierToken.new lexem
           end
        else
          lexem << char
      end
    end
  end

  def eof
    nil
  end

  def delimiter
    @delimiter
  end

  def quotes
    '"'
  end
end
```

---

**assertions.rb**

```
# An exception to represent assertion violations.
#
class AssertionError < RuntimeError
end

# Evaluates the given block as a boolean expression and throws an AssertionError
# in case it results to false.
#
def assert &block
  raise AssertionError unless yield
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`if not`**

It is very 'unruby' to use `if not`. Ruby has a special `unless` just for these cases:

```
  unless last_seen_identifier
    values << ""
  end
  break
```

You can even shorten this further by using the one-liner shorthand:

```
values << "" unless last_seen_identifier
break
```

One more general guideline - although you can have an `unless .. else .. end` construct, it is not recommended. Better to reverse the conditional:

```
# not good
if not last_seen_identifier
  values << ""
  next
else
  last_seen_identifier = false
end

# not better
unless last_seen_identifier
  values << ""
  next
else
  last_seen_identifier = false
end

# better
if last_seen_identifier
  last_seen_identifier = false
else
  values << ""
  next
end

# best
values << "" unless last_seen_identifier
last_seen_identifier = false
```

**Too Many Classes**

Contrary to languages like Java or C#, Ruby is not statically typed, but rather [duck typed](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html), which means that you can pass any type anywhere, and the objects don't have to inherit from the same base class.

For example, the class `Token` adds no functionality, and it is not used anywhere in the code besides being inherited by a bunch of classes. It is totally redundant, and deleting it will not affect the code.

Furthermore, `EOFToken` and `DelimiterToken` don't contain any intrinsic functionality, and according to ruby's idioms, a better solution would be to simply pass symbols (`:eof` and `:delimiter`) rather than classes.

The last token (`IdentifierToken`) holds the current value, but you can even skip that, simply passing the value itself instead.

This will make the token iteration look like this:

```
tokens.each do |token|
  case token
    when :eof
      values << "" unless last_seen_identifier
      break
    when :delimiter
      values << "" unless last_seen_identifier
      last_seen_identifier = false
    else
      if last_seen_identifier
        raise ParseError, "Unexpected identifier - a delimiter was expected."
      end
      last_seen_identifier = true
      values << token
  end
end
```

**Assertions?**

[Assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28software_development%29) are used by some languages to make some development checks where a condition is assumed to be always true. This methodology is not longer en-vogue in most places, and even where it is - it is also disabled in production:

> Most languages allow assertions to be enabled or disabled globally,
>   and sometimes independently. Assertions are often enabled during
>   development and disabled during final testing and on release to the
>   customer. Not checking assertions avoids the cost of evaluating the
>   assertions while (assuming the assertions are free of side effects)
>   still producing the same result under normal conditions. Under
>   abnormal conditions, disabling assertion checking can mean that a
>   program that would have aborted will continue to run. This is
>   sometimes preferable.

In your code the need for the assertion seems a bit artificial, since it checks that the first character is exactly the character pushed back by the caller:

```
...
  when quotes
    stream.unshift char
    get_quoted_identifier stream
...

char = stream.shift
assert { char == quotes }
```

that being the case, I would argue that you can remove the unshift/shift tango, and simply *assume* that the first char is `quotes`:

```
...
  when quotes
    get_quoted_identifier stream
...

char = quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `UnsupportedDelimiterException` class is very clean. I particularly like that you over rode the `to_s` method so that it returns something meaningful. It's a little detail that often gets over looked. Well done.

That said, I'm not sure what you're really getting from the `ParseError` class.

> ```
> class ParseError < RuntimeError
> end
> ```

Yes, it's nice to get a parse error rather than a runtime error, but that's all you're gaining. It seems a little silly to inherit from a class and then have the *exact* same functionality.

Comment: I disagree. It is a very good idea to have separate error classes. It allows you to rescue parse errors **only**. If you didn't do this, you'd have to rescue all StandardErrors, check the error message and re-raise the exception if you cannot handle it. It's not about functionality in this case, but about providing context and semantics.

Comment: That's a very valid point @britishtea. Feel free to downvote my answer if you think it's bad advice.

Comment: This is indeed bad advice. If someone would be using this code and receive only `RuntimeError` it would be harder to find what the problem is.  I understand your point and would agree if would have been something like `class SpecificParseError < ParseError` that would maybe not have helped, but giving context to the caller is important.